# Application Has Stopped , I have to bind listview with data in Fragment

Tags: android, xml

i am working on an assignment on listview in fragments.
i have a fragment class
i have to Bind the List/Collection of Contacts with listView.
My listview must be in fragment

```
public class Listviewfragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<Contacts> list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
private ListView l;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list.add(new Contacts("omar"+i,"03214"+i));
    }

    l = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    l.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),list));

}
```

}

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
@NonNull
private final Context context;
@NonNull
private final ArrayList<Contacts> list;
private TextView t1,t2;
public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context,  @NonNull ArrayList<Contacts> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {
    Contacts u = (Contacts) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
    t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t1.setText(u.getName());
    t2.setText(u.getNumber());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Contacts class

```
public class Contacts {
private String name;
private String number;

public Contacts(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

}

There are no errors but but "Application has stopped"
layout for main activity that includes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:name="com.example.hp.myapplication.Listviewfragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/listviewfragment"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout for fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i dont know what did i make wrong in it

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: do i have to make filter for my logcat or just i have to paste logcat with no filters

Comment: You can copy and paste only the part that made the application crash

Comment: my application does'nt starts.Application has stopped pops up

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Please add xml file

Comment: just added the xml files

Answer (score 0):

check the last line in the first `xml` posted

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayou t>
```

you have a "space" in `ConstraintLayout` fix it to:

```
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: that space happened while posting it here.

Comment: Ok so edit the question and correct it it is misleading.